# How to disable particular dynamic checkbox in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

Kindly see the below object array.i am displaying all group description value along with checkbox. i m trying to disable B and C group but as values are coming dynamic, all checkbox values are getting disabled.how can i disable particular group checkbox here.

```
[{groupId: "4", groupDesc: "A"},
 {groupId: "12", groupDesc: "B"},
 {groupId: "23", groupDesc: "c"},
 {groupId: "34", groupDesc: "D"}]


 for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
         if(array[i].groupDesc == B || array[i].groupDesc == c)
            {
                 this.disablecheckbox = true;
            }
    }
<ng-container *ngFor="let value of array;let i = index;">
    <input type="checkbox" pattern="[0-9]{10}" [disabled]="disablecheckbox == true"  value="{{ value.GroupId }}" /><i class="skin"></i><span style ="width: 150px;">{{ value.groupDesc }}</span>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Why are you using `this`? That's doesn't seems to be disabling the checkboxes

Comment: i have set Boolean flag in typescript.

Comment: not related to your issue as I am not really familiar with Angular but instead of chaining all the or statements, you can do if ([‘A’, ‘B’, ‘C’, ‘D’].includes(array[i].groupDesc) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a particular object from forEach to modify the property instead of local variable:

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
    if(array[i].groupDesc == A || array[i].groupDesc == B || array[i].groupDesc == c || array[i].groupDesc == D)
    {
      array[i].disablecheckbox = true;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let value of array;let i = index;">
    <input type="checkbox" pattern="[0-9]{10}" [disabled]="value.disablecheckbox"  value="{{ value.GroupId }}" /><i class="skin"></i><span style ="width: 150px;">{{ value.groupDesc }}</span>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: in this case also all checkbox will be disabled right.i need one B and C to be disabled

Comment: then why there is A and D in the if block? recheck your if condition!

Comment: if i remove also both will not disable at a time . it will take last value. so only D will be disabled

Comment: Hi I added Html Code as well. please help me out

Comment: @user3363946 have to checked? Working?

Comment: @user3363946 Can you give a stackblitz demo? Where I can test it?

Comment: @user3363946 Seem working here check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g9fhzs